# Perform commands on terminal programmatically

Tags: c#, bloomberg

I am looking to open on the terminal pages such as the security description for a given ticker programmatically. I am aware that this is possible using the Dynamic Data Exchange and executing for instance `<blp-1><home>MSFT US<EQUITY><GO>DES<GO>`, however I would like to avoid using DDE if possible.

Ideally I would be looking to communicate with the terminal using the blpapi as I understand that this is the supported approach, is anyone aware of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDE is no longer supported for sending command to terminal, it is replaced by TerminalConnect, a special Api to integrate your application with the terminal, including:
 1. Sending commands from your application.
 2. Update security hotspot on the LP Component groups.
 3. Receive notifications of hotspot changes.
 4. Embedding certain LP Components into your app (like CHART)
 5. And lately, populating the LP Worksheets with securities (formerly known   as LP Monitors).

The Api is available in .NET and Java.

You can download the SDK from the terminal: type SDK then select SDK then Terminal Api.